# Streisand Effect and Turnkey Linux on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, github, turnkey

I'm new to linux and I currently have a Raspberry Pi 3 running Turnkey Linux that I plan on using as a File Server in my home. I'm still working on this project and following this [tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/id/Ultimate-Pi-Based-Home-Server/). I came across this [Streisand Effect github page](https://github.com/StreisandEffect/streisand) and was wondering if I installed this, will it modify my File Server setup or prevent me from finishing this project?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the SAMBA file server in that tutorial? I don't think Streisand would mess with that configuration. If you're trying to access your file server from outside the home, it looks like you'd have a lot of routing considerations to get past all of the security measures in Streisand. I can't answer for sure without a use case and basic config information.

That said, go ahead and try it! Sounds like a great learning experience either way.

Comment: Yes the SAMBA file server. thanks! I'll try it and see. When it comes to the routing considerations, can you give me an example? @JohnMoon

Comment: Sure! It depends on what features of Streisand you'd be using and how strict you'd want to be about maintaining privacy. I see Streisand has OpenVPN with it, so maybe one setup would be to have your SAMBA server only share with devices on the LAN, then have your VPN act as an outside gateway to that LAN (the way most enterprises do). It all depends on your use case and how tight or loose you'd like security to be.